# Https hook target url not invoked in podio

Tags: podio

Need help to investigate why my https hook target url is not properly invoced in Podio. 
I suspect there is a certificate issue, even though the certificate is valid for the domain.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the hook in an App, Podio will make a `verify` call to the url that you provided(Also, You can trigger the verify call programmatically.). You have to `validate` the hook using the code received from the verify call. The hook will become active only after on successful validation.

Refer Podio documentation here,

- [Request hook verification](https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/request-hook-verification-215232)
- [Validate hook verification](https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/validate-hook-verification-215241)

Also they have a detailed tutorial on [Working with Webhooks](https://developers.podio.com/examples/webhooks)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have had the implementation working for a year and half, but we have renewed our certificates and also a new operations provider. When using the url from webRequest in poweshell the server is hit. When using http the server is also hit. Is there any way I can find out what is happening i Podio?

Answer (score 0):

Reproduced the error using django and rest hooks, resulted in error : (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))). Used https://www.ssllabs.com/ and found a certificate chain issue. I suppose this is the problem.